# How can I detect if an environment is right after a sectioning command?

Tags: sectioning, environments, conditionals

I'd like to build an environment that would detect if it is right after a sectioning command (`\section`, `\subsection` or `\subsubsection`) and smart enough to detect if a `float`-type environment (say `figure`) has been inserted between the sectioning command and itself. Here is a sketch of what I have in mind (written for the `article` class, my real case is with the `book` class, but I don't think it matters that much).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifRightAfterASectioningCommand
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  % Some detection mechanism
  % that sets RightAfterASectioningCommand
  % to true or false
  % ...
  \ifRightAfterASectioningCommand
    Right after a sectioning command
  \else
    Not right after a sectioning command
  \fi
  }{}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is false
\end{myenv}

\section{Section}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is true
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is false
\end{myenv}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is true
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is false
\end{myenv}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is true
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is false
\end{myenv}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is true
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
% RightAfterASectioningCommand is false
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifRightAfterASectioningCommand==\if@nobreak`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All sectional command globally set the internal conditional `\if@nobreak` to true. This conditional is reset to false as soon as a paragraph is started. However, floats would change it only if really typeset at the spot. The rationale is that a float appearing immediately after a sectional title counts as the first paragraph after the title.

You probably will be satisfied with

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  % Some detection mechanism
  % that sets RightAfterASectioningCommand
  % to true or false
  % ...
  \if@nobreak
    Right after a sectioning command
  \else
    Not right after a sectioning command
  \fi
  }{}
\makeatother
```